# IP Address showing instead of Domain apache server

Tags: apache, web, raspberry-pi

I just purchased a domain from GoDaddy, **let's call it example.com**. I set up my A record and CNAME to properly point to my home IP address (see picture below) where I run an Apache2 server on my Raspberry Pi.
[image: Records from GoDaddy]
My 000-default.conf file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html 
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            AllowOverride All
            Options All
            Require all granted
            # Any other directives
        </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I have searched the internet for hours and even asked another question on StackOverflow to where I thought the problem was resolved, however after about an hour of restarting the Apache2 service on the Raspberry Pi, it goes back to showing my home IP Address in the address bar instead of my newly purchased domain. I have tried restarting the service multiple times but I always end up with the same result. Flushing DNS on my devices does nothing, too. How can I make it so that it **always** shows my domain in the address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in your Domain provider (GoDaddy for example) that you aren't forwarding to your IP address. Instead, forward to your domain.